# On p5JS canvas changing background image showing already drawn objects behind the background image

Tags: p5.js

I'm drawing some objects on canvas but if later I change the background image on demand, then already drawn objects are behind the background image. How to bring already drawn objects in front. Below is the sample code i'm using to change the background image.

```
function draw() { if(chnBg){ //if change background is clicked loadImage("images/Grid_Image.png",function(bg){
background(bg);
}); } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set `globalCompositeOperation` to `destination-over` before drawing / changing the background image ...

```
let canvas;

// setup
function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
}

// draw
function draw() {
  if (chnBg) { //if change background is clicked 
    loadImage("images/Grid_Image.png", function(bg) {
      canvas.drawingContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'; //<-- set this
      background(bg);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just store your state in a data structure of some kind and redraw everything each frame.

Another approach would be to draw your objects to a buffer graphics instead of directly to the canvas. Then draw the background to the canvas, and then draw the buffer to the canvas.

More info is available in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics).

Comment: thanks a lot, Kevin Workman..your solution is also working. I have a question "will keeping drawing in data structure or in buffer will have any impact on RAM?"

Comment: @Tanzeem The only way to be sure is to do some measurements yourself. But generally, storing everything in a data structure gives you more freedom and control, but also takes more time and requires more memory. Using a buffer image requires a constant amount of memory, but gives you less freedom and control. Which approach you take depends entirely on your context.